# Debugging java code for SPOJ STPAR

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to solve this problem on SPOJ
http://www.spoj.com/problems/STPAR/

My code is written in the following link:
[My Solution](https://ideone.com/4QPyxS)

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        Scan sc = new Scan();
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(System.out);

    while(true)
    {
        int n = sc.scanInt();

        if(n == 0)
            break;

        ArrayStack<Integer> stack = new ArrayStack<>();
        int[] arr = new int[n+1];
        arr[0] = -1;

        // without using an extra array
        // for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            // arr[i+1] = sc.scanInt();

        boolean isOrdered = true;
        int count = 1, number;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            // System.out.println("i: " + i + " n: " +n + " count: " + count);
            // number = arr[i+1];
            number = sc.scanInt();

            while(stack.peep() != null && stack.peep() == count)
            {
                // pr.print(stack.pop() + " ");
                // System.out.println("From 2");
                stack.pop();
                count++;
            }

            if(number == count)
            {
                // System.out.println("From 1");
                count++;
            }
            else
            {


                if(stack.peep() == null || stack.peep() > number)
                {
                    // System.out.println("From 3");
                    stack.push(number);
                }
                else if(stack.peep() <= number)
                {
                    // System.out.println("From 4");
                    isOrdered = false;
                    // break;
                }
            }
            // else
                // pr.println("From 5");

            // System.out.println("stack: " + stack.toString());
        }

        // pr.println();

        if(isOrdered)
            pr.println("yes");
        else
            pr.println("no");
    }   

    sc.close();
    pr.close();
}
```

I have seen all the comments on that problem. All the mentioned test case are passed for my code, but still it is giving NZEC after submitting. I have also searched for solutions on the internet most of them looks like my solution. After trying to solve it for more than 2 hrs I am posting this question. 
Please help me in debugging the my code.

Sorry if it looks naive!!

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my solution to the question:

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        while(n!=0)
        {
            int arr[]=new int[n], k=1;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
            int stack[]=new int[n], top=-1, i=0;
            Arrays.fill(stack, 0);
            while(i<n)
            {
                if(arr[i]!=k)
                {
                    if(top<0)
                    {
                        top=top+1;
                        stack[top]=arr[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if(stack[top]==k)
                    {
                        top--;
                        k++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        top=top+1;
                        stack[top]=arr[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    k++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            for(i=top; i>=0; i--, k++)
                if(stack[i]!=k)
                    break;

            if(k==n+1)
                System.out.println("yes");
            else
                System.out.println("no");
            n=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```